# Does $x=\frac{1}{2^n-3}$ converge in both directions in $\Bbb{Z}_2$ for $n$ an integer?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

> Does $x=\dfrac{1}{2^n-3}$ converge in both directions in $\Bbb{Z}_2$ for $n$ is integer?

Solving $x=\dfrac{1}{2^n-3}$ for $x$ where $n$ is integer.

We get that the only the solutions in $\Bbb{Z}$ are $x\in\{-1,1\}$ and of course there is a countable set of solutions in $\Bbb{Q}$ given by:

$x\in\left\{\ldots,-\frac{4}{11},-\frac{2}{5},-\frac{1}{2},-1,1,\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{13},\ldots\right\}$

Does this sequence $x_n$ converge in both directions in $\Bbb{Z}_2$?

To the right (i.e. $n\to\infty$) we have $x\to \dfrac{1}{2^{m}-3}$

To the left (i.e. $n\to-\infty$) we have $x\to \dfrac{-2^m}{2^m+2^{m-1}-1}=2^{2m}\cdot\dfrac{-1}{1+2^{2m-1}-2^m}$

I have no doubt that to the right it converges to $-\frac{1}{3}$.  Is that correct?

To the left I'm not so sure.  I think all but the $1$ in the denominator  converges to $0$ leaving me with $0\cdot \frac{-1}{1}=0$.  Is that correct?

Comment: I'm utterly baffled as to why this question would be downvoted and voted to close.

Comment: Let's prove that it converges to $-1/3$ when $n\to\infty$: We have that $|1/(2^n-3)+1/3|=|2^n/(2^n-3)|=2^{-n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: For $n\to-\infty$ it converges to $0$: Since $|1/(2^n-3)|=|2^{-n}/(1-3\cdot 2^{-n})|=2^n\to0$ as $n\to-\infty$.

Comment: @totoro thanks. Much appreciated.

Comment: No `\dfrac` in titles please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put this into a bit of perspective, I figure I will post this as an answer to a broader case. In general, if we look at the expression $\dfrac{1}{x^{-1} + a^{-1}}$ it tends towards $a$ as $x$ gets larger in magnitude and tends towards $0$ as $x$ gets smaller in magnitude, regardless of what field you're in, real or p-adic.

Specifically here we can let x play the role of $p^n$ and $a$ play the role of $\dfrac{-1}{3}$.